# What do you call sentence structures with unnecessary pronouns?

Tags: terminology, syntactic-analysis

Examples:
"The father, he was very angry." instead of "The father was very angry"
"The cup, it was overflowing." instead of "The cup was overflowing"

I have seen it in dramatic texts, especially where a special emphasis is needed for dramatic effect. But recently I have heard this guy on youtube do this with almost every sentence with a subject and it's jarring and weird.

I wonder what this grammar style is called.

Comment: That sort of thing is becoming less common, because (sorry not sorry) the times, they are a-changin'.

Comment: @nnnnnn You say that, and yet some people seem to relish in using it (and overusing it), it seems.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hm, possibly. It's not really the same question, but about the same topic.

Comment: 'Left dislocation' seems a pretty convincing answer for 'X, he was y'. Certainly a duplicate (the banked response hedges). We'll be having " ' Z, she was z' isn't really a duplicate" if we're not careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choices people make in how they present the information they want to convey is called *information packaging* or *[information structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_structure)*.

The sentence *The father, he was very angry* packages the information to place greater emphasis on the subject of the sentence than the standard *The father was very angry*.

This type of construction is called *left dislocation* by the *The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* (p1408). The CGEL explains dislocation:

> A dislocated clause has a constituent, usually an NP, located to the
>   left or the right of the nucleus of the clause, with an anaphorically
>   linked pronoun or comparable form within the nucleus itself.

It gives the example:

> Her parents, they seem pretty uncaring.

According to the CGEL, "*dislocation of this kind is often found in oral personal narratives and informal writing*".

Comment: Thank you, that's a very clear and concise answer.

Comment: @batjko. Thanks. And the right dislocated version of your sentence is: _He was very angry, the father_.